# Restrict a smooth drag in draggable jquery-ui

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am dragging a div within a main div with respect to y-axis.

```
$("#childdiv").draggable({axis:'y'});
```

It drags smoothly in y axis. But I want a drag with jerks..

**For Example :** When I start drag .. the draggable component directly moves to 50px and if I again drag next jump will be to 100px next drag will directly jump to 150px . *It should be simillar like sortable with placeholder but using draggable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the `grid` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-grid) to get this:

> Snaps the dragging helper to a grid, every x and y pixels. The
>   array must be of the form [ x, y ].

eg.

```
$("#childdiv").draggable({
    axis:'y',
    grid: [0, 50]
});
```

Here's an example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1epL4ea/

Comment: wow this is awesome ....i searched so much regarding this but  i could not get anything about grid. Why so ?

Comment: I wanted exactly this . So , number 50 is in pixels ?

Comment: Yes, 50px. Since you're not using the x axis, it doesn't matter what the first number is